# Using R for simulation based power analysis of Multi-Factor Within-Subjects Repeated Measures ANOVA

Tags: r, simulation, anova

I have been trying to run a power analysis for study design that will be analyzed by a 4 factor Repeated Measures ANOVA where all factors are within-subjects. After a lot of searching and some help on Cross Validated, it is clear that I need to

- Do a simulation where I generate data based on some pilot data I have
- Run it through the appropriate anova model
- And then iterate to find the average power.

The code pasted below was found at [this link](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/80190/power-analysis-of-repeated-measures-anova-using-simulation-in-r?newreg=183b499633d240a6a3a4a9c2e1890eb7), and it seems to do exactly what I want to do, albeit for only a 2 factor within-subjects ANOVA.

However, I am having trouble understanding all of the details and what specific lines do because I am very new to R. I would be very grateful if anyone could shed some light on these lines of code:

My questions:

1. Why is the intercept for all conditions set to -1? Is that standard to this model?
   intercept = rep(-1, nconds)
2. Do the values in these columns represent the levels of the x1 and x2 factors or are they SDs etc? If they are the levels, shouldn't the levels for `x2` be `(0, .5, 0, .5)`?

   ```
   true.effect.x1 = c(0, 0, .5, .5)
   true.effect.x2 = c(0, .5, .5, .5)
   ```
3. What mean and SDs do I take from my pilot data (from multiple subjects) for these three lines of code?

   ```
   #relatively large subject-specific variance in intercepts
   sub.intercept = rep(rnorm(nsub, mean=0, sd=2), times=1, each=nconds) 
   #relatively small by-subject adjustments to the effects
   sub.effect = rep(rnorm(nsub, mean=0, sd=0.05), times=1, each=nconds) 
   #unexplained error
   error = rnorm(nsub*nconds, mean=0, sd=1)
   ```

I know this is a very long question but I would really appreciate any help anyone could provide! Thank you so so much!

FULL CODE

```
library(ez)

nsub = 30
nconds = 4

nsims = 100

#create an empty matrix that will be populated with p-values 
p = matrix(NA, nrow=nsims, ncol=3)

#subject vector
sub = sort(rep(1:nsub, nconds))

#2x2 factorial design
cond = data.frame(x1=c('a','a','b','b'), x2=c('c','d','c','d'))

# fixed effects 
intercept = rep(-1, nconds)
true.effect.x1 = c(0, 0, .5, .5)
true.effect.x2 = c(0, 0.5, .5, .5)
X = rep((intercept + true.effect.x1 + true.effect.x2),nsub)

#simulation loop
for (x in 1:nsims)
{

#random effects

#relatively large subject-specific variance in intercepts
  sub.intercept = rep(rnorm(nsub, mean=0, sd=2), times=1, each=nconds) 

#relatively small by-subject adjustments to the effects
  sub.effect = rep(rnorm(nsub, mean=0, sd=0.05), times=1, each=nconds) 

#unexplained error
  error = rnorm(nsub*nconds, mean=0, sd=1)

#simulated dependent variable
  observed.y = X + (sub.intercept + sub.effect + error)

#place everything in a data frame
  df = cbind(sub, cond, observed.y)
  names(df) = c('sub','x1','x2','y')
  df$sub = as.factor(df$sub)

#extract the p-values for each effect from a repeated measure ANOVA (ezANOVA from 'ez' package)
  p[x,1] = ezANOVA(data=df, dv=.(y), wid=.(sub), within=.(x1, x2))$ANOVA[1,5]
  p[x,2] = ezANOVA(data=df, dv=.(y), wid=.(sub), within=.(x1, x2))$ANOVA[2,5]
  p[x,3] = ezANOVA(data=df, dv=.(y), wid=.(sub), within=.(x1, x2))$ANOVA[3,5]
}

###### p-values < .05 ? ######
sig.x1 = ifelse(p[,1] <= .05, 1, 0)
sig.x2 = ifelse(p[,2] <= .05, 1, 0)
sig.int = ifelse(p[,3] <= .05, 1, 0)

###### Histograms ######
par(mfrow=c(3,1))
hist(p[,1], 20, xaxp=c(0, 1, 20), col=2, main = paste('power X1:', mean(sig.x1 * 100), '%  with ', nsub, 'subjects'))
hist(p[,2], 20, xaxp=c(0, 1, 20), col=2, main = paste('power X2:', mean(sig.x2 * 100), '%  with ', nsub, 'subjects'))
hist(p[,3], 20, xaxp=c(0, 1, 20), col=2, main = paste('power interaction:', mean(sig.int * 100), '%  with ', nsub, 'subjects'))
```

Comment: Incidentally, the following web application for experimental data simulation may be useful in the present context: https://github.com/pablobernabeu/Experimental-data-simulation

Answer (score 0):

1) Because -1 = -sum(true.effect.x1) and the author that you were incompletely copying only had one "true.effect". They wanted a sum-type of contrast. This is suggesting to me that you don't have a sufficient background in statistics to really understand this project.

2) No, they represent covariate values against which coefficients will be estimated. You could use contrasts like c(-2,0,1,1) and the beta estimate would have been one-half what it would be for c(-1,0,-.5,-.5). Think of them as categorical indicators. "Dummy variables" is one term that is used.

3) The question is confusing and I think it is you that are confused and not me. The sd specified is twice the effect, and I think you have copied the comment above from another source without understanding.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it was very helpful. I am the first to admit that I am not a statistics expert and am a few years out from my last formal statistics course; however, I think that my lack of familiarity with R compounded any confusion I had with the statistical concepts. Also, the code I provided was not an 'incomplete copying' of someone else's code as you put it. That is the entire code they provided and their Q had no explanation of its functionality. Thank you again for your help and I hope that if I have more questions you will be able to help then as well. Thanks.